# Upgrading from Aem 5.6 to AEM 6

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, aem

We have some of our apps developed for AEM5.6. All the apps are working fine on AEM5.6. We are using JSP for view. However, when I deploy these same apps on AEM6.0, it simply stops working. There's no error in logs while deploying the app to aem6. But, when I open any of the pages, the pages are simply blank. We have used some custom taglibs in our application.
   Do I need to make any changes in JSP to make it work on AEM 6.0? There are absolutely no errors in logs after deployment.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade.html ?

Comment: I would just check that you're using the correct java version (java 7), and monitor server startup. If you cannot find the cause there or in the log file, I think it would be reasonable to contact adobe support.

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust your Maven dependencies accordingly:

http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2014/05/aem6-maven-dependencies.html

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the bundle list and checked, if there are any unmet dependencies for your bundle or any other bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the recent requests on your AEM instance.  For example:
`http://localhost:4502/system/console/requests`

This will tell you how the request was handled, what servlets/components/jsps were invoked during the processing of the request and whether there were some errors in that processing.

Answer (score 0):

You said there were no errors in the logs WHILE deploying.  But if you have issues causing the pages to not display (like classes being missing) then that will show up when you try and load the page.  So look for errors there. and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the service pack 2.0. It brought lots of fixes. In addition, try starting the server using the command line, if you are not doing so already, in order to get some extra log messages other than the default ones.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the WebConsole - OSGi bundles (http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles) if there are some bundles that are not active and needs some dependencies.?

Answer (score 0):

you must check for errors after showing the blank jsp. meanwhile try to recompile your bundles using the new sling and aem dependecy versions some deprecated method are removed. this will generate runtime errors.